# JSP Not Rendering

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, server

I am very new to JSPs, we were given some code as example in a Uni. tutorial but it's not working.

This is my Server.java

```
public class Server{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Server server = new Server(8080);

        // As we are using the Servlet to server responses remove the resource handler.
        ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
        resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
        resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{"index.jsp", "index.html"});
        resource_handler.setResourceBase("./target/classes/webapp");

        // Initialise Servlet context handler
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(
                ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");

        // Add Servlets with holders to context handler
        ServletHolder indexHolder = new ServletHolder(new IndexServlet());
        context.addServlet(indexHolder, "/index.jsp");

        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] {context, resource_handler, new DefaultHandler() });
        server.setHandler(handlers);

        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

    }
}
```

This is my Index Servlet

```
public class IndexServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0x1C30CCL;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Set response content type.
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);



    }


}
```

This is my index.jsp

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Book a hotel!</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="index.jsp" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" />
<input type="Submit">
</form>
<p> The current server time is: <%= new java.util.Date() %> </p>

</body>
</html>
```

When I access localhost:8080/index.jsp the Data in the <% %> is not parsed! Help

Comment: The servlet is calling itself with that `forward()` call.

Comment: How do I process the JSP? All the examples I've seen use this forward call, but how do I get the JSP file to show up?

Comment: What is your servlet supposed to do? Right now it's doing nothing.

Comment: I just want to show the "index.jsp" as HTML when I go to localhost:8080/index.jsp -- it should just show the HTML plus the data

Comment: Try going to localhost:8080/ - what do you get? Same error?

Comment: I get: HTTP ERROR: 404 for that

Comment: Either change the servlet to a filter, or rename the servlet to something other than `index.jsp`. Remember, JSP files are compiled to servlets by the container, so you're clashing on URL paths. Your servlet and the JSP has the *same* path. Servlet wins.

Comment: I don't think I am allowed to use a filter, the example has to work via a servlet, and I am only allowed one .jsp file where GET and POST requests are made, sorry. I'm from a PHP/Apache background so the concepts of a servlet are still vague and new to me

Comment: Are you saying that you have to submit a request localhost:8080/index.jsp and it has to go to index.jsp via a servlet? What directory is the index.jsp in?

Comment: That's how I interpreted the instructions, they're here: http://i.imgur.com/pqCD8Oq.png from how I interpreted the English text, it sseems to imply that I have to handle GET/POST using this index.jsp.Look under the last part of the imgur link

Comment: I did remove forward but it's not processing my <%= new java.util.Date() %>

Comment: Starting with JSP development with an embedded Jetty Server might not be the most straightforward way to do so. How about a plain-vanilla install of tomcat - and then just place some .jsp files into `tomcat/webapps/ROOT/` and see how they do.

Comment: Unfortunately, my specification constrains that though I agree with you. I've got .jsps working now, by reworking my whole structure, but I am struggling to get servlets to register, I'll set up a new question if I don't make any progress.